# Grab immediate parent tag from a given text

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I have extracted all non-empty texts from a webpage and stored each piece of text in a list using:

```
text = response.xpath('//text()[normalize-space()]').extract()
```

Now I want to check which piece of text lies between H1 tags. Given a piece of text, is it possible to grab the immediate parent tag surrounding it using xpath?

I am scraping on top of Scrapy framework.

Answer (score 1):

According to docs, what you get is the list of plain strings, so I assume they don't store any references to the tree they were extracted from:

> `extract()`
>
> Serialize and return the matched nodes as a list of unicode strings. Percent encoded content is unquoted.

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#scrapy.selector.Selector.extract

It seems that if you need only text surrounded by `<h1>`, you will have to specify it in your xpath selector and query with it.